# How to use Insert in MongDB:s Function

Tags: mongodb

Goal: use MongoDB's function to add new row by using function.

It is similar concept to add a new row by using a stored procedure in SQL Server.

Problem: the code doesn't work and what part am I missing?

```
{
    "message" : "db.Test.myAddFunction is not a function",
    "stack" : "script:1:10"
}
```

Info: I'm new to MongoDB

```
db.createCollection("Test")


db.inventory.insertMany([
   { item: "journal", qty: 25, tags: ["blank", "red"], size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" } },
   { item: "mat", qty: 85, tags: ["gray"], size: { h: 27.9, w: 35.5, uom: "cm" } },
   { item: "mousepad", qty: 25, tags: ["gel", "blue"], size: { h: 19, w: 22.85, uom: "cm" } }
])

db.system.js.save(
   {
     _id : "myAddFunction" ,
     value : function (x, y)
     { 
        db.inventory.insertOne(
           { item: "canvas", qty: 100, tags: ["cotton"], size: { h: 28, w: 35.5, uom: "cm" } }
        )         

        return x + y; 
     }
   }
);

db.loadServerScripts();

db.Test.myAddFunction(2, 2);
```

Comment: So you cannot, and the documentation clearly says you cannot. The real issue here I you appear to be looking to create "stored procedures", and despite what misleading blog post you might have read somewhere, there is no such thing as stored procedures with MongoDB. It's just not how it's designed, and any sever JavaScipt usage really should be treated as a feature which would be expected to eventually be removed. If you're honestly stuck on thinking this is what you need, then I would advise choosing a database which actually supports it. MongoDB does not.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

> Once you save a function in the system.js collection, you can use the function from any JavaScript context; e.g. **$where** operator, **mapReduce** command or **db.collection.mapReduce()**.

Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/